# Надо ли ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Скажем, есть такая подпись: "Твой дед(,) Иван Иванович". Нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В подписи - нужна.
А в тектсе - по смыслу. Если "Иван Иванович" добавлено чтобы не подумали на другого деда, Ивана Никифоровича, скажем, то без запятой. Ну а если это просто для полного титулования, то нужна.